# jquery .load Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm learning how to load and modify web content on client side without page load and postbacks.

I want to load the content of `Controls/content.html` into the div just like i saw on multiple exemples :

here's the div and button :

```
<input type="button" id="btnHtm" onclick="Content()" name="Menu" value="HtmAppear" />
<div id="htmlCont"></div>
```

here's the content :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
           <h4> HELO </h4>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the file path :

,[image]

Edit : deleted other trys

Here's my fourth try :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >

$(document).ready(function content() {
    $('#htmlCont').load("Controls/content.html");
});

</script>
```

Comment: When you include a script for some file, you can not put code inside. You need a script separate to your code.

Comment: @alexqoliveira  the script is placed inside the Header content "content1" of my aspx, and the div is place in "content3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector need a #. Try this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#htmlCont').load("Controls/content.html");
    });

</script>
```

Comment: See my edit, it does not work, if you think i misunderstood the syntax, please provide a complete answer...

Comment: Sorry about that, but when you include a script for some file, you can not put code inside. You need a script separate to your code. I edited my answer.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: content is not defined

Comment: try to remove the name of the function 'content'.            $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#htmlCont').load("Controls/content.html");
    });

Comment: yeah but how will my event be liked to my input button then ?

Comment: `<input type="button" id="btnHtm" onclick="$(document).ready(function() { $('#htmlCont').load('Controls/content.html');});" name="Menu" value="HtmAppear" />` this works... but its not like i really have a function for it...

Comment: To name a function where you need to write: https://jsfiddle.net/alexqoliveira/optxw1w7/

Comment: Ok... I see the hello only 0.0001 seconde then it disapear.... what the hell is that, aint jQuery supossed to be client side, i see it act like postback...

Comment: Well... you've helped at least, i'll accept your answer and just stop using jQuery

Comment: Maybe sometime i'll put the whole function inside the OnClick="" of a button...but it's goin to be ajax for the rest